# Jquery UI and pluggin hotkeys conflicting scripts (or am I wrong?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hotkeys

I'm currently trying to put into place **Jquery UI** to enable **drag and drop** feature on my site, as well as **hotkeys for shortcuts**.  But there seems to be a conflict.

Check out my **jsfiddle** here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cgv5Z/

You will see that drag and drop is not functional at the moment, but if you delete in the JS panel the script for the hotkeys, the drag and drop works.

Questions:

**1.** Can you help me find a way to fix it?

**2.** If not, is there an alternative to hotkeys to create keyboard shortcuts that would work with jquery UI?

Any help on this topic would be very much appreciated.  **Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works loading jQuery 1.7 and the UI through jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Cgv5Z/2/

One thing you might check is your ordering of scripts.

Comment: Using the newest version of jquery.hotkeys there is another bug leading to exactly the same issue. (see http://jsfiddle.net/zMxbD/3/ for reproducing) But madpin provided a fix for this bug on github: https://github.com/madpin/jquery.hotkeys